# Invalid qualifier VB excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm developing a macro that add an hyperlink to each cell of the selected column.

Im adding a counter to add +1 to the name of the link at the cell, It compiles but when I execute it says me "Invalid Qualifier".

My code as follows is:

```
Sub MeterHipervinculos()
   Dim sh As Worksheets
   Dim rw As Range
   Dim counter As Long

   Set sh = Sheets(Hoja1)
   counter = 0

   For Each rw In sh.Rows
       If sh.Cells(rw.row, 7).Value = "" Then
           Exit For
       End If
       If sh.Cells(rw.row, 8).Value = "" Then
          sh.Cells.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="FOTOS\CM" + 
            counter.ToString("D4") + ".jpg", _
               TextToDisplay:="FOTOS\CM" + counter.ToString("D4") + ".jpg"
       End If
       counter = counter + 1
   Next rw
End Sub
```

What's wrong with the code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no  counter.toString  in vba. Use Cstr(counter) perhaps? Not really sure where you are going with that bit.

Comment: What is Hoja1 ?

Comment: Sheet1 is Hoja1 Lol. So I guess meant worksheet. Which I guess means counter should be  contador.......

Comment: There are multiple things wrong with the code. For starters, replace the first line with this code `Dim sh As Worksheets: Set sh = Sheets("Hoja1")` and then edit your question with some debugging and specific error messages

Comment: Jeeped and QHarr, Hoja1 is the Sheet1 of the current worksheet. Hoja1 is working, I think that main problem is that there isn't a .ToString("D4") function at VBA.

Comment: sh.Rows should probably be something like sh.usedrange.Rows; you don't want a million hyperlinks.

Comment: Jeeped,I check that issue with the line: "If sh.cells(rw.row, 7).value = "" then exit for ".

Comment: What string are you hoping to construct with `counter.toString("D4")`? How is the value of `counter` to be combined with  `"D4"`?

Comment: "FOTOS\CM00001.jpg", "FOTOS\CM00002.jpg"... and so on.

Comment: Try `"FOTOS\CM" & String(5 - Len(Str(counter)), "0") & counter & ".jpg"` Note that the code will throw an error if `counter` exceeds 9999.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot to all! :D

Comment: A superior alternative to the code in my other comment is :`"FOTOS\CM" & Format(counter,"0000") & ".jpg"`. The use of the [Format function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/language-reference-vba/articles/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) is a better match for what you were trying to do with your original code.